# is there any API's is exists for uploading a file into the share point (office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Is there any API's there to upload a file to the share point location (office 365) ?

I have already tried with graph Api but which have only get method so please assist me on this,

I have already gone through below links,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

For uploading files smaller than 4MB:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

For uploading files bigger than 4MB they have to be uploaded in batched using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0